# WSO2 Identity Server – How to write a XACML Policy for an Extended PIP

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac, wso2-identity-server

A PIP extension code using a "RedAttributeFinder" class is working now. It correctly register its claims  into the WSO2 PDP extension console display.

I start to create a XACML policy now, addressing  the field that returns the dynamic data value delivered by the extension program (for example a field named "http://w3.red.com/subject/employeeCountryCode").

The key field for a data look-up is: `urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id` 
, which maps a user identity in an email format.

**Question 1:**  How is invocation of the “getAttributesValues” method done at the "RedAttributeFinder" class, registered at the start of WSO2. What triggers the call of the method from the PDP process (or its incoming requests)?

In the sample code, as well as at my implementation, the key field is the resource-id which is loaded as part of the PEP request implementation.

```
..
myRequest += "<Attributes Category=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject\">" + "\n"; 
myRequest += "<Attribute AttributeId=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id\" IncludeInResult=\"false\">" + "\n"; 
myRequest += "<AttributeValue DataType=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string\">tony@br.red.com</AttributeValue>" + "\n"; 
myRequest += "</Attribute>" + "\n";  
myRequest += "</Attributes>" + "\n"; 
myRequest += "<Attributes Category=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource\">" + "\n"; 
myRequest += "<Attribute AttributeId=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id\" IncludeInResult=\"true\">" + "\n"; 
..
```

This is the key input for the "getAttributesValues()" and will return a country code (similar to the role [blue, silver, gold] definition in the WSO2 example code [  available here https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.samples.entitlement.pip/ ] .

In the sample, I see that the required resolution of roles value, for example "blue" is part of the Policy target definition.

**Question 2:**  Is this placement inside target section a requirement to call the dynamic PIP look-up, one per requests, or can it also be placed at other parts of the policy, like for example inside a rule?

I was able to test the PEP to PDP interaction with a rule definition, only by defining static variables, receiving "permit", a rule that I would like to change to the dynamic data obtained from the PIP implementation and its extension, addressing the new fields added by the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a standard implementation that complies with the XACML standard, the PDP will invoke the PIP any time it finds an attribute designator in its policies that is also published by the PIP (it means the PIP must advertise which attributes it can provide e.g. it provides role, citizenship...).

The PDP could choose not to call a PIP and to use an attribute cache instead. The placement of the attribute in the policy is irrelevant. Whether the attribute is used inside a target or a condition should not matter - according to spec at least - and that is how the Axiomatics, SunXACML, and ATT engines all work.

Cheers,
David.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a useful debug option in the WSO2 setup by adding this line into log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement=DEBUG
```

This command started to trace the requests sent to the PIP, including the call to the PIP extension class (by attribute designator) and returning data fields.

This confirmed that the PIP is called dynamically by the PDP, as well as the Try-It function. The policy below delivered the expected "permit" and "deny" results, by this confirming proper functioning of the PIP extension program.

Below a very simple policy that was tested with a PIP extension code fetching a value for the data variable named: employeeCountryCode.

**Policy**

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyId="RedLDAPPolicy1" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:permit-overrides" Version="1.0">
<Target>
</Target>
<Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Permit-Rule1">
<Target>
<AnyOf>
<AllOf>
<Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">631</AttributeValue>
<AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://w3.red.com/subject/employeeCountryCode" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true">
</AttributeDesignator>
</Match>
</AllOf>
</AnyOf>
<AnyOf>
<AllOf>
<Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">ldap</AttributeValue>
<AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true">
</AttributeDesignator>
</Match>
</AllOf>
</AnyOf>
<AnyOf>
<AllOf>
<Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
<AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true">
</AttributeDesignator>
</Match>
</AllOf>
</AnyOf>
</Target>
</Rule>
<Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="Deny-Rule">
</Rule>
</Policy>
```

**Request**

```
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false">
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">tony@br.red.com</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="true">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">ldap</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
</Request>
```